# How do I access my object array as a datastore across multiple node modules in 'use strict' mode?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, module, scope

So I am using an object array as my datastore. Every module is in 'use strict' mode so globals do not work. I tried creating a a single module to store my data and including it on several modules, however it fails to work.

`list.js`

```
'use strict';

module.exports.list = [];
```

I'll have other files access this, for example, the main code, and then a test file. I need to be able to access and manipulate the array from every file list is included. All i get is modules crashing.

`code.js`

```
var list = require('./list.js').list;
    list = [{id:1},{id:2},{id:3}];
```

Trying to run the specs, just crashes everything, removing the datastore makes tests fail.

`code_spec.js` --tests

```
var list = require('./list.js').list;
    fixtures = [{id:1},{id:2},{id:3}];
list = fixtures;
```

Comment: I don't see why these two line of code should crash the engine. Anyways, `list = [{id:1},{id:2},{id:3}];` will only change the local variable `list`, it won't affect `list` of the other module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't actually updating the singleton instance of list. You want to use a setter and a getter for this. You can use the concept of `closures` for this to access the local variable inside list.js.

```
//list.js

var list = [];

module.exports.get = function () {
    return list;
}

module.exports.set = function (ll) {
    if (Array.isArray(ll)) {
        list = ll
    }
}
```

and how to use it in your other file:

```
//other.js

var listService = require('./list');

list = listService.get();

newList = listService.set([{id:1}, {id:2}, {id:3}]);

console.log(listService.get()); //[{id:1}, {id:2}, {id:3}]
```

Another possiblity which I would only use for certain things is to use the `global` object:

```
global.list = [{id:1}, {id:2}, {id:3}];
```

this can be used throughout the app. But DON'T polute your global space.